# nrf24l01 Module not Working with Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I can use the [nrf24l01 wireless module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/705) just fine with a Raspberry Pi Pico, but when I try to compile the same code on the Raspberry Pi Pico **W**, it fails to recognize the device. I am using [this](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/micropython/drivers/radio/nrf24l01) library, and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 31, in <module>
File "nrf24l01.py", line 78, in __init__
OSError: nRF24L01+ Hardware not responding
```

The boards are supposed to have the same footprint, so what is the difference here? How can I use these modules with the Pico W?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is the result of faulty wiring or a bad NRF24L01 module. One thing that you should also check is that your SPI interface is set up correctly. For example, SPI(0) defaults to using GPs 2, 3 and 4 (pins 4, 5 and 6, respectively).

```
>>> SPI(0)
SPI(0, baudrate=3906250, polarity=0, phase=0, bits=8, sck=2, mosi=3, miso=4)
```

Thus, you should use pin 4 for SCK, even though technically pins 9 and 22 can also be used for SCK. If you really want to use these other pins, you'll have to specify the pins manually using the `SPI` constructor.

Comment: This is actually what ended up solving it, though there was no faulty wiring or bad sensors. I will post my solution here soon. Thanks!